# How to use NOT FIND_IN_SET in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

As we use FIND_IN_SET to search in comma separated values in Laravel like:

```
->whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET(2,sent_mail_ids)')
```

But now I want to get those results which do not exist in comma separated values. To do this we use NOT FIND_IN_SET in MySQL, but how to use this in Laravel?

Comment: `->whereRaw('NOT FIND_IN_SET(2,sent_mail_ids)')`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**whereRaw()** allows you to add any arbitrary SQL code to your query - in order to reverse the constraint simply use the same query you'd use in raw **SQL**:

```
->whereRaw('NOT FIND_IN_SET(2,sent_mail_ids)')
```

or another variation of this constraint:

```
->whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET(2,sent_mail_ids) = 0')
```

Comment: @Insomania Not storing your data in such a way so you dont need find in set is the most correct.But as to the 2 versions above it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Mihai, i am sorry i didn't get you

Comment: @Insomania choose what ever you want, the first one is more readable I think

Comment: I'd go for the first form as it explicitely tells you what the check does - you don't need to care or know what the return value of FIND_IN_SET is